# how to assemble vite -> vue3 into one .js file?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

Good afternoon.
tell me how to assemble vite -> vue3 into one .js file?

@vitejs/plugin-vue with the CustomElement: true parameter

collects css styles but css styles does not work
there are no errors in the console